# awk print full line before the matched pattern

Tags: bash, awk

**RE-WRITTEN POST**

**Important**
*Good morning all, thank you for your comments and answers, I am not in my computer at the moment so I may need to try some answers later on and I'll mark the one that worked for me as the correct solution. i apologise if my wording from this post wasn't the best one, I was exhausted last night that I did not even check my wording before posting this post. *

I will clarify a bit better my question:

So i have a script which we will call `./run.sh`and Inside of that script i have a variable which is call `SCRIPT=DIR`

This variable runs a command
`cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd`

So the full variable looks like:

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"
```

Then below that variable i have an echo which prints the variable SCRIPT_DIR
 `echo $SCRIPT_DIR`
and when i run the script `./run.sh` I get printed the following string
`/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/scripts/boot/`

My question is, by using awk to remove text from the given string, I would like to remove `scripts/boot/` So, I was thinking of matching a patter like `scripts/`  and print every line that is before `scripts/`. By only matching `scripts/` with awk, i would like to be able to have a result such as :
`/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/`

I was looking for a long period of time and I couldn't find and answer to something similar, i tried the command that was given by someone else in another post, which prints what is before a matched pattern, i tried to modify that command to fit my script but no success. Hope this is better to understand!

Sorry again

---- **PREVIOUS POST** ---- **PLEASE IGNORE**
so I am aware there are numerous posts trying to solve this question; however, I have had not succeeded in achieving that! So I have a script that tells me the directory from where my bash script is located which I took from another post:

```
#SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"
/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/scripts/boot
```

I am trying to remove the */scripts/boot* directory from the result so it would end up being:

`/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/`

I am trying to use `awk` as my solution, I know there are other commands like grep or perl but I rather use awk just to keep it consistent. Does anyone know how can I achieve that? I have had so many unsuccessful attempts

Someone suggested on another post to use

```
awk '/foo/{if (a && a !~ /foo/) print a; print} {a=$0}' file
```

But I couldn't make it work. Additionally, I have not much experience with bash so I couldn't figure out a way to solve it. Any help?

Comment: not sure I understand the 2 lines of 'script' you've posted ... are you saying the `SCRIPT_DIR` variable contains the string `/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/scripts/boot`? or is the string `/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/scripts/boot` a hardcoded line in the script (and if so what is the significance of the `#SCRIPT_DIR=` line)? what does any of this have to do with the subject `print full line before the matched pattern` ... what 'pattern' and what 'full line'?

Comment: I can't imagine what that awk script you posted could have to do with the problem you're describing and the example you gave, it's utterly unrelated (but it COULD make sense to a problem as stated in your subject `awk print full line before the matched pattern`), so that makes me think maybe you aren't describing your problem well enough here. Also, do you **literally** want to remove the string `/scripts/boot` from the end of the original string or do you actually want to remove the last 2 path segments no matter their values?

Comment: You say `I rather use awk just to keep it consistent` but there's no awk in the code you posted so - consistent with what?

Comment: If you remove `/scripts/boot` from `/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/scripts/boot` the result is `/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1`, not `/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/`, please [edit] your question to fix either the string you want to remove or the expected result of removing the string.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this message late at night i was tired, I will clarify i bit better! So i have a script has a variable called SCRIPT_DIR, when i run that command I can an echo $SCRIPT_DIR which prints out the directory from where my script is located. Of course SCRIPT_DIR is the variable!. Sorry for the confusion. Additionally, I am trying to use awk to remove the strings /scripts/boot/ from my echo if that makes sense

Comment: I have updated my post, sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear but maybe this is what you're trying to do, i.e. just populate SCRIPT_DIR with the path to the directory 2 levels above the one where your script exists?

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/../.." &> /dev/null && pwd )"
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i have posted a better explained post, hope that makes more sense! thank you for your answer i'll give it a try once i arrive to my office today, i'll let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an AWK command which deletes the trailing part:

```
$ echo /home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/scripts/boot | awk 'match($0, "/scripts/boot$") { print substr($0, 1, RSTART - 1) }'
/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1
```

Comment: `awk 'sub("/scripts/boot$","")` would be more concise and efficient.

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `awk`, you could use `sed`, as in:

```
echo /home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/scripts/boot | sed 's/scripts\/boot$//'
```

This will give you as output:

```
/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/
```

Comment: Whenever you have `/`s in the regexp or replacement string you should use some character other than `/` as the delimiters so you don't need to escape those `/`s, e.g. `sed 's:/scripts/boot$::'`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Your solution `sed 's:/scripts/boot$::'` will give `/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1` as output, without a trailing `/`, which is not what the PO asks for. He wants `/home/vMX-ENV/vMX-21.1R1/` as output. See above.

Comment: Obviously if you don't want to include the leading `/` then just don't, that wasn't the point of my comment, but they also said `I am trying to remove the /scripts/boot` so take your pick of requirements, hence [my comment under the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70323835/awk-print-full-line-before-the-matched-pattern/70324316?noredirect=1#comment124314672_70323835).

Comment: @EdMorton: I also obviously agree with your comment about changing the delimiters. I just opted for escaping the `/` for making it easier for a rather new user as the PO to understand my `sed` command.